# Soap API integration in PHP: SoapClient Error

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

When I use the XML in sopaUI the results are coming out fine, but when I use the following php code the the result comes out blank and I get this error: `Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Saia.Presentation`. I think the problem is in the Soap header or something because when I comment out the parameters there's no change in the result.

Link from where I got the wsdl file and schema: http://www.saiasecure.com/webservice/pickup/n_Create.asp

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://www.saiasecure.com/webservice/pickup/soap.asmx?wsdl",array( 'trace' => 1,
'exceptions' => true,'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS, ));

$params = array("UserID" => '*******',
        "Password" => '*****',
        "TestMode" => "Y",
        "AccountNumber" => '******',
        "CompanyName" => 'TESTING NAME',
        "Street" => 'TESTING STREET',
        "Box" => 'TESTING BOX',
        "City" => 'LOS ANGELES',
        "State" => 'CA',
        "Zipcode" => '90001',
        "ContactName" => 'TESTING CONTACT',
        "ContactPhone" => '1234567890',
        "PickupDate" => '2013-09-24',
        "ReadyTime" => '13:00:00',
        "CloseTime" => '17:00:00',
        "SpecialInstructions" => 'Nothing',
         "Details" => array("DetailItem" => array("DestinationZipcode" => '70364', "Pieces" => '5', "Package" => 'SK',"Weight" => '100', "Freezable" => 'N') ));
    //print('<pre>');print_r($params);  
$return = $client->Create($params);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look to the WSDL you'll see that the `Create` operation parameter must contain a `request` element that points to the actual `Create` object parameter (that you can send as you did with an associative array).

I must say that the WSDL is not very correct because the same element name, meaning `Create` is used twice for a different définition. Once as `element`, once as `complexType`.

To be clear, you have to do so with your actual code : `$return = $client->Create(array('request'=>$params));` and it should work.